# Listar diretórios e subdiretórios

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, treeview

Eu tenho um componente TreeView, e uma estrutura no banco que ja tem na tabela diretórios os subdiretórios.
tem um campo chamado diretorio_parent_guid, se ele for nulo é porque é raiz, se não, é algum Id de outro diretorio.
Então eu tenho a seguinte estrutura:

Método que retorna diretorios: esperando um parametro que vai listar somente os diretorios com parent guid igual a string passada:

```
internal List<Diretorio> GetSubDiretorio(String termo)
{
    using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
    {
        var diretorios = (
            from dir in ctx.DIRETORIO 
            where dir.DIRETORIO_PARENT_GUID == termo
            select new Diretorio()
            {             
                DIRETORIO_GUID = dir.DIRETORIO_GUID,
                XDIRETORIO = dir.XDIRETORIO,                
                REFERENCIA = dir.REFERENCIA
            }
        ).ToList();     
        return diretorios;
    }
}
```

Preenchimento do treeview que eu tentei:

```
public void CriarTreeView()
{
    var raiz = DiretorioController.GetInstance().GetSubDiretorio("");
    foreach (var diretorio in raiz )
    {      
        node = new TreeNode(diretorio.XDIRETORIO);
        node.ImageUrl = "~/asstes/img/directory.png";
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);

        foreach (var subDiretorio in DiretorioController.GetInstance().GetSubDiretorio())
        {
              TreeNode nodeSub = new TreeNode(subDiretorio.XDIRETORIO);
              nodeSub.ImageUrl = "~/asstes/img/directory.png";
              node.ChildNodes.Add(nodeSub);
        }
    }
}
```

Dessa forma esta funcionando diretorios e subdiretorios, porem fica manual, se eu crio um diretorio dentro de um subdiretorio ele não lista, não consegui aplicar a lógica correta ainda.
Como ficaria para listagem dos subdiretorios corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para percorrer a arvore até as folhas, você precisa utilizar de recursão:

```
public void CriarTreeView()
{
    var diretorios = DiretorioController.GetInstance().GetSubDiretorio("");
    foreach (var diretorio in diretorios)
    {      
        node = new TreeNode(diretorio.XDIRETORIO);
        node.ImageUrl = "~/asstes/img/directory.png";
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        this.CriarTreeView(diretorio, node)
    }
}

public void CriarTreeView(Diretorio diretorio, TreeNode node)
{
    var subDiretorios = DiretorioController.GetInstance().GetSubDiretorio(diretorio.DIRETORIO_GUID);
    foreach (var subDiretorio in subDiretorios)
    {      
        TreeNode subNode = new TreeNode(subDiretorio.XDIRETORIO);
        subNode.ImageUrl = "~/asstes/img/directory.png";
        node.ChildNodes.Add(subNode);
        this.CriarTreeView(subDiretorio, subNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma esta criando o terceiro diretorio, porem se eu seleciono o primeiro novamente, ele cria abaixo do segundo sempre.

Comment: Então agora os eu problema é outro, considere fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Deu certo, valeu